# SimpleSlider, support for a last slider value callback

Tags: jquery, ajax

I try the slider values to send to the ajax function, but I need only the last values.

```
$(".range-input").simpleSlider({
    range: [1, 100],
    value: 80,
    step: 1
}).bind("slider:changed", function (event, data) {
    var sliderValue = data.value.toFixed(0);
    $(this).parent().click(function (event) {
        console.log('value: ' + sliderValue);
    });
});
```

I get...

value: 1 
value: 2 
value: 3 
value: 5

etc.

How do I get the last value to send on my ajax-function?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try [debouncing](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_debouncing) the changed value, the underscore library has a good debounce method which you can use to create a wrapped and debounced version of your original function...

http://underscorejs.org/#debounce

your code would then look something like this

```
var frequencyOfTrigger = 300;

var sliderChanged = _.debounce(function(event, data) {
    var sliderValue = data.value.toFixed(0);
    $(this).parent().click(function (event) {
        console.log('value: ' + sliderValue);
    });
}, frequencyOfTrigger);

$(".range-input").simpleSlider({
    range: [1, 100],
    value: 80,
    step: 1
}).bind("slider:changed", sliderChanged);
```